# ListView using Custom Adapters

Tags: android, listview

I have created a class Country.java and made my custom adapter myListAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter. I am not getting any messeges in my LogCat either but the application crashes at line:

```
countName.setText(" "+currentCountry.getCountryName());
```

so what is wrong here how can i get CountryName?

```
public class Country{
    private String countryName;
    private String capitalName;

    public Country(String countryName, String capitalName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.capitalName = capitalName;
}

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public String getCapitalName() {
        return capitalName;
    }
}
```

here is class myListAdapter

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country>{

        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, myCountries);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }

            Country currentCountry = myCountries.get(position);

            TextView countName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_countryName);
            countName.setText(" "+currentCountry.getCountryName());

           TextView capName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_CapName);
           capName.setText(currentCountry.getCapitalName());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

item_view.xml is:

```
<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_countryName" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_CapName" />
```

Comment: What is `myCountries`? Where does it come from?

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67 refer this link. It's good to use ViewHolder for Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the below code in your adapter : 

 TextView countName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_countryName);
            countName.setText(" "+currentCountry.getCountryName());

           TextView capName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_CapName);
           capName.setText(currentCountry.getCapitalName());
```

**Edit My Code :**

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,
        R.layout.item_view, myCountries);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: it didnt help, still application crashed

Comment: Can you share your Exception. Are you still getting Nullpointer Exception?

Comment: i am getting this following exception

Comment: W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163ec80)

Comment: check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952377/got-threadid-1-thread-exiting-with-uncaught-exception-group-0x41088930-on-lis

Answer (score 0):

Are you fire the `getView()` method manually?  You should `@Override` this method like below. If you set the adapter and the screen is loaded, `getView()` is automatically triggered.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    }
```

and you should use `findViewById()` method like below;

```
TextView countName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_countryName);
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT. i was miising 

(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_countryName);

Comment: I am glad to help you. Is it working without override the getView() method?

Comment: no actually I override the getView() method but when I paste the code here i missed it mistakenly.